# Scoring Method for Swift & Spawning objects

Tags: ios, swift, timer, collision, scoring

I cannot seem to work out how to get my scoring to work...

the concept of the game is birds will come in on the right hand side, and when they reach the left hand side i want my score to increment by 1.

In Obj_c i would have done something like

```
if (bird.enter.x < 0) {
    score++
}
```

but in swift sprite kit I'm not to sure how to do it...

Another problem I'm having is that i have to use a timer to get my "Enemy Birds" to spawn (the birds going from right to left)

(every 1 second the timer runs the spawn enemy function) but in Obj_c i would have spawned say 3/4 at different x co-ordinates and like the previous code when the bird was < 0 px i would `CGPointMake()` back over to the other side of the screen so they are on a constant loop

Any ideas of doing this in swift? My code is as follows: its in bit of a weird layout:

```
import SpriteKit





class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var bg = SKSpriteNode()             // Create Background
var bird = SKSpriteNode()           // Create User Bird
var scoreLabel = SKLabelNode()      // Create Score Label
var score: Int = 0                  // Create Score Integer
var enemyBird = SKSpriteNode()      // Create Enemy Bird

var birdGroup:UInt32 = 1            // Bird Collision Group
var objectGroup:UInt32 = 2          // Enemy Collision Group
var scoreGroup:UInt32 = 3           // Score Collision Group
var gameOver = 0                    // Game Over function
var movingObjects = SKNode()        // ??
var gameOverLabel = SKLabelNode()   // Game over label
var labelHolder = SKSpriteNode()    // Holds Label - Game Over
var Menu = 0


/* Put Bird in and animate */
var birdTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bird_img_1.png")
var birdTexture2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bird_img_2.png")
var birdTexture3 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bird_img_3.png")
var birdTexture4 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bird_img_4.png")

var birdDeadTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bird_img_dead.png")

var finalSpawn: CGFloat = 0.0


/* ------------------------------------ Main Setup ------------------------------------------ */


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    println("Moved to Game Scene")


    movingObjects.speed = 0




    /* Call Functions */
    backgroundImage()
    enemySpawn()



    /* Set up deletates and physics and timer */
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, -5)
    self.addChild(movingObjects)
    self.addChild(labelHolder)


    /*  Load Score Text */

    scoreLabel.fontName = "Helvetica"
    scoreLabel.fontSize = 60
    scoreLabel.text = "0"
    scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)+self.frame.size.height*0.3)
    self.addChild(scoreLabel)


    enemyBird.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.width+200, 500)
    movingObjects.addChild(enemyBird)



    bird = SKSpriteNode(texture: birdTexture)
    bird.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    // Make bird smaller
    bird.size.height = bird.size.height/12
    bird.size.width = bird.size.width/11
    // Animate Bird
    var animation = SKAction.animateWithTextures([birdTexture, birdTexture2, birdTexture3, birdTexture4], timePerFrame: 0.08)
    var makeBirdFlap = SKAction.repeatActionForever(animation)
    bird.runAction(makeBirdFlap)
    // Load Physics
    // birdPhysics()
    // Run bird animation
    bird.zPosition = 10


    self.addChild(bird)


    /* Introduce ground and top into the scene */
    // Create Ground
    var ground = SKSpriteNode()
    ground.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), self.frame.size.height/100 * 16)
    ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, 1))
    ground.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    ground.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup
    // Add Ground to scene
    self.addChild(ground)

    // Create Top
    var top = SKSpriteNode()
    top.position = CGPointMake(0, self.frame.size.height)
    top.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, 1))
    top.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    top.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup
    // Add Top to scene
    self.addChild(top)


}








/* ------------------------------------ Spawning Enemy Birds ------------------------------------------ */








/* Create and Spawn enemy birds */
func enemySpawn() {





    let height = self.frame.size.height                             // screen height as variable
    let width = self.frame.size.width                               // screen width as variable

    var bottomBarHeight = self.frame.size.height*0.16               // bottom bar height
    var spawningPoint = height - bottomBarHeight                    // screen height - 16%

    var randSpawn = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(spawningPoint))       // random number between 0 and 645
    finalSpawn = CGFloat(randSpawn) + bottomBarHeight           // add 16% (bottombarheight to the random number
    println(Int(finalSpawn))





    if (enemyBird.position.y > frame.size.height) {
        enemyBird.position.y = frame.size.height - 100
    }

    if (enemyBird.position.y < self.frame.size.width * 0.16) {
        enemyBird.position.y = self.frame.size.width + 0.18
    }




   // Create enemy bird
    var enemyBirdTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "enemy_img_2.png")

   // enemyBird.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.width+200, 500)
    enemyBird = SKSpriteNode(texture: enemyBirdTexture)
    enemyBird.size.height = enemyBird.size.height/12
    enemyBird.size.width = enemyBird.size.width/11
    enemyBird.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(enemyBird.size.width/1.1, enemyBird.size.height/1.1))
    enemyBird.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    enemyBird.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = objectGroup

   // BIRD LOOP - ONLY RUNNING ONCE???        

    let startPoint = CGPointMake(self.frame.width+200, finalSpawn)
    let endPoint = CGPointMake(0, finalSpawn)
    let moveToEndAction = SKAction.moveTo(endPoint, duration: 2)
    let resetTostartAction = SKAction.moveTo(startPoint, duration: 0)
    let moveToEndThenStartAgain = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([moveToEndAction,resetTostartAction]))

    enemyBird.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveToEndThenStartAgain))

}











/* ------------------------------------ Other Parts ------------------------------------------ */








func backgroundImage() {

    /* Put Background Image In */

    // Create Background Texture
    var bgTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "bg.png")
    // Link bg variable to texture
    bg = SKSpriteNode(texture: bgTexture)
    // Position thr bg image
    bg.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: self.frame.height/2)
    bg.size.height = self.frame.height

    // Move background image left
    var moveBg = SKAction.moveByX(-bgTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 9)
    var replaceBg = SKAction.moveByX(bgTexture.size().width, y: 0, duration: 0)
    var moveBgForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([moveBg, replaceBg]))

    // Keep world never ending
    for var i:CGFloat = 0; i < 3; i++ {

        // Position Background
        bg = SKSpriteNode(texture: bgTexture)
        bg.position = CGPoint(x: bgTexture.size().width/2 + bgTexture.size().width * i, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

        // Stretch background full height of screen
        bg.size.height = self.frame.height

        // Run the action to move BG
        bg.runAction(moveBgForever)

        self.addChild(bg)
    }
}










/* ------------------------------------ Create Bird Physics ------------------------------------------ */








func birdPhysics() {
    /* Give bird physics */
    // Give bird physics
    bird.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bird.size.height/3)
    bird.physicsBody?.mass = 0.2
    bird.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    bird.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    bird.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = birdGroup
    bird.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = objectGroup
    bird.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = objectGroup


}









/* ------------------------------------ If contact is found ------------------------------------------ */










func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == objectGroup || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == objectGroup {


        bird.removeAllActions()
        bird.texture = birdDeadTexture
        let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(-M_PI), duration:1)
        bird.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))


        if gameOver == 0 {
            movingObjects.speed = 0
            gameOver = 1
            movingObjects.removeAllChildren()// Remove all enemies
            gameOverLabel.fontName = "Helvetica"
            gameOverLabel.fontSize = 25
            gameOverLabel.text = "Tap to retry!"
            gameOverLabel.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)*1.5)
            labelHolder.addChild(gameOverLabel)
            gameOverLabel.zPosition = 9


        }
    }
}












/* ------------------------------------ When user touches the screen ------------------------------------------ */






override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */




    if (Menu == 0) {
        movingObjects.speed = 1
        birdPhysics()
        let action = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(-M_PI), duration:1)
        bird.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(action))

    }




    if (gameOver == 0) {                                                                            // Runs if game is not over
        bird.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
        bird.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 80))
        Menu = 1    // Number on right is jump height


    } else {                                                                                        // Runs if game is over
        score = 0                                                                                   // Score int is 0
        scoreLabel.text = "0"                                                                       // Score Label is 0
        bird.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))         // Position Bird in center
        bird.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0,0)                                              // Cannot make bird jump
        labelHolder.removeAllChildren()                                                             // Removes all labels
        gameOver = 0                                                                                // Sets game over to 0 so game will run
        movingObjects.speed = 1
        bird.texture = birdTexture
        // Animate Bird
        var animation = SKAction.animateWithTextures([birdTexture, birdTexture2, birdTexture3, birdTexture4], timePerFrame: 0.08)
        var makeBirdFlap = SKAction.repeatActionForever(animation)
        bird.runAction(makeBirdFlap)

        let height = self.frame.size.height
        let width = self.frame.size.width



            var gameScene: GameScene = GameScene(size: CGSizeMake(width, height))
            var spriteView: SKView = self.view as SKView!
            var trans :SKTransition = SKTransition.crossFadeWithDuration(0.5)
            spriteView.presentScene(gameScene, transition: trans)

    }
}







override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    if (enemyBird.position.x == 0) {

        score = score + 1
        scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
    }


    if (enemyBird.position.y > frame.size.height) {
        enemyBird.position.y = frame.size.height - enemyBird.size.height
    }  
}    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase the score like

```
if (bird.position.x < 0)
{
    score++
}
```

And to loop the animation of enemy birds, you can make a looping `SKAction` from one end to other end. For example like this

```
let startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 200)
let endPoint = CGPointMake(self.frame.width, 200)

let moveToEndAction = SKAction.moveTo(endPoint, duration: 2)
let resetTostartAction = SKAction.moveTo(startPoint, duration: 0)

let moveToEndThenStartAgain = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([moveToEndAction,resetTostartAction]))

node.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveToEndThenStartAgain))
```

To start at a random height each time, you can use

```
let maxHeight:UInt32 = 400
let startPoint = CGPointMake(0, CGFloat(arc4random() % maxHeight))

let moveToEndAction = SKAction.moveByX(self.frame.width, y: 0, duration: 1.0)
let resetTostartAction = SKAction.runBlock { () -> Void in

    let randomHeight = CGFloat(arc4random() % maxHeight)
    self.playButton.position = CGPointMake(startPoint.x,randomHeight)
}

let moveToEndThenStartAgain = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([moveToEndAction,resetTostartAction]))

enemyBird.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveToEndThenStartAgain))
```

You can change `maxHeight` as required.

Comment: Would this code go inside the viewDidLoad? the reason i could not use the if < 0 statement was because it was inside a function which was being called by a timer which only ran once to launch the bird Im guessing it will require a whole restructure of my code?

Comment: You can check the position of the bird sprite in the update function

Comment: Sorry I've been at this game for about 3 days non stop and its all confusing me now haha.

Right the only problem with this is that i still have a timer running the function for spawning enemy birds. If i was to remove the timer and just all my enemySpawning function once how would i incorporate the finding X co-ordonate into it?

Comment: There is an update function in skscene. It is called every frame. You can check the position of your node inside that.

Comment: https://spritekitlessons.wordpress.com/2013/10/08/using-the-update-method-of-your-skscene-to-update-other-nodes/

Comment: Cannot believe i forgot about this! That did the trick! only problem is that with your bird code i get a random bird spawning at point (0,0) which moves upwards to the y co ordinate i set (say 500) then the birds start coming in from the right hand side (which is what i would like to happen)

Comment: I didn't understand the problem. Cant it be solved by changing start and endpositions

Comment: Thats all sorted now pal, last thing and my game is nearly done, You've been such great help i will be uprooting you as soon as i have the reputation...

Anyway - The first bird is okay and spawns at a random height but after that they all spawn at the same Y Co-ordinate

Comment: First enemy bird or your bird?

Comment: The first enemy bird will spawn at a random height but then all enemy birds after that will spawn at the same level because the function to spawn enemy birds is only being run once inside ViewDidLoad (so although the enemy bird is on a loop its still only being run (and generating a random number for the height spawn once)

Comment: its not just one enemy bird on the screen at a time? do u mean that you want to respawn  the enemy bird at a different after it goes out of screen?

Comment: yes pal exactly, only 1 bird on the screen at one time (maybe more in the future) but for now just 1 bird spawning at a different height every time is what i am going for

Comment: That did the trick..... But no matter what i do i have a bird spawn at 0,0, even if i CGPointMake(200,200) in the view did load i still have it spawn at 0,0  (enemy bird this is) something weird is going on i will update my code now...

Comment: make the startPoint height also random. like in my code.